# String interpolation in ERB getting commented out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a piece of code from Michael Hartl's tutorial Chapter 9, Listing 9.43 (copy pasted straight from the tutorial). It is to be placed in a `users.yml` file.

The third line (name:) is getting commented out after the # sign. So this part  `{n}" %>` is commented out. The fourth line ("email:") works fine as there is a dash (`-`) linking the string together. If I add a dash to the `name:` line, then the second quote in that line matches with the first quote of the "email:" line, creating a string out of `%> ... email: <%=`.

Any idea how to fix this?

```
<% 30.times do |n| %>
  user_<%= n %>:
    name:  <%= "User #{n}" %>
    email: <%= "user-#{n}@example.com" %>
    password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If it's just your editor's syntax highlighting getting confused then I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. When I paste the code in other files, such as an html.erb file or a controller file, it is highlighted fine. But in the test/fixtures/users.yml, there is no highlighting whatsoever, only the unwanted commenting out. Guess it's something to do with users.yml specifically.

Comment: A YAML file with ERB in it isn't a valid YAML file (it becomes a valid YAML file after ERB processes it), so your IDE doesn't know how to highlight it. If you make your IDE to highlight it as ERB instead the ERB highlighting should be fixed but you'll lose the YAML highlighting.

Comment: Good info. So, does the highlighting affect the function, say in the case in my OP? Or will the string interpolation, even though its highlighted as being commented out, still work as intended? Or is it invalid therefore it won't work?